# send multiple keyboard combinations

Tags: 16.04, xubuntu, xfce

I am on a fresh install of Xubuntu 16.04.

I would like to be able to press something like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> and have it do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> and then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd>. Is there anyway to do this?

Or instead of kicking it off with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> I could use one of the numerous programmable keys on my keyboard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checkout [xdotool](https://www.semicomplete.com/projects/xdotool/xdotool.xhtml). You can create a bash script that uses xdotool to trigger your Ctrl+Alt+1, sleep for a second, then use xdotool again to trigger Ctrl+Alt+2. For example:

```
#!/bin/bash 
xdotool key "ctrl+alt+1"
sleep 1
xdotool key "ctrl+alt+2"
```

Make that bash script executable with

```
chmod +x <path to bash script>
```

Then add ctrl+h to the xfce4 keyboard shortcuts with your bash script as the target. You can use the command:

```
xfce4-settings-editor
```

to open the xfce4 settings editor. Good Luck!

Comment: Do you know if this works within remote viewers like Citrix? When I am in Citrix full screen I have to press CTRL+F2 to tell Citrix to send the next keys to the host OS and then CTRL+M to minimize. Was hoping to replace that with one shortcut...